# How to properly get these records' values returned from a database query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, graphql

I've been wondering about this for a long time. I did something questionable to solve this problem before. But I don't know how to get this to work with Graphql now. Let me show you what I mean.

I've got a database query returning the following:

```
{edges: COLLECT(DISTINCT {source: id(endNode(r)), target: id(startNode(r))})}
```

The object returned looks like this:

```
{ edges: [ { source: [Object], target: [Object] } }
```

next, the source and target objects look like this:

```
[ { source: Integer { low: 38, high: 0 },
    target: Integer { low: 37, high: 0 } },
```

I only need the low value. To get there, I went all this way:

```
.then(function (result) {
  return result.records.forEach (function (record) { 
    return record._fields[0].edges.forEach (function (a) { 
      return a.source.low
})})});
```

I tried to figure out how to do this in a nice way for a very long time. I've spent days just trying to figure out this maze of undefined values. But now,
I need to get the same id numbers out of a Graphql resolver. This what my .then part of the resolver looks like:

```
.then(function (result) { return result.records.map(function (record) { return record.get("{edges: COLLECT(DISTINCT {source: id(endNode(r)), target: id(startNode(r))})}").edges })})
```

This returns an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[ { source: Integer { low: 38, high: 0 },
    target: Integer { low: 37, high: 0 } }]
```

This is where i'm stuck. No matter what I can think of, everything returns undefined. I want to do the following query in graphql: `{edges{source target}}`
But Graphql won't even get close to returning a result.

if I try something like

```
.then(...).edges.source
```

an undefined value will be returned. I've tried every combination I could think of, but I seem not able to make Graphql query these id numbers, let alone return a value that is not undefined.

I can get the desired result like this:

```
var arr = [];
.then(function (result) {
   return result.records.forEach (function (record) {
      return record._fields[0].edges.forEach (function (a) {
         return arr.push({source: a.source.low, target: a.target.low})
    })})});
```

But I've got no clue on how to return arr to graphql.

To get an idea of the resolver functions. This is what a working resolver for a user query looks like:

```
user(_, { userID }) {
  let session = driver.session();
  let query = "MATCH (a:user) WHERE a.userID = toInteger$userID RETURN a;";
    return session.run(query, {userID})
      .then(function (result) { return result.records.map(function (record) { return record.get("a").properties })})
```

Please help me out of this maze

**EDIT:**

The object I am trying to create looks like this:

```
Object
links:
Array(22)
0:{source: 36, target: 44}
1:{source: 44, target: 45}
2:{source: 44, target: 46}
3:{source: 44, target: 48}
4:{source: 44, target: 47}
5:{source: 44, target: 53}
6:{source: 44, target: 62}
7:{source: 36, target: 52}
8:{source: 52, target: 58}
9:{source: 36, target: 54}
10:{source: 54, target: 56}
11:{source: 54, target: 55}
12:{source: 55, target: 63}
13:{source: 55, target: 60}
14:{source: 54, target: 61}
15:{source: 36, target: 49}
16:{source: 49, target: 59}
17:{source: 49, target: 50}
18:{source: 49, target: 51}
19:{source: 49, target: 65}
20:{source: 52, target: 57}
21:{source: 52, target: 64}
length:22
__proto__:Array(0)
nodes:(23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__:Object
```

I've got the nodes, but I'm seriously stuck with creating the array of objects for the links. The resolver for the link data looks like this:

```
const resolveFunctions = {
    Query: {
        nodes(_, {userID}) {
            let session = driver.session();
            let query = "MATCH p=(w) -[*]- () WHERE id(w) = toInteger($userID) UNWIND nodes(p) AS n UNWIND relationships(p) AS r WITH n, r ORDER BY n.Name RETURN n, {nodes: COLLECT(DISTINCT n), edges: COLLECT(DISTINCT {source: id(endNode(r)), target: id(startNode(r))})};";
            return session.run(query, {userID})
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.records.map(function (record) {
                        return record.get("n").properties
                    })
                })
        },
    },
    Node: {
        source: (name, _) => {
            let session = driver.session();
            let params = {nameParam: name.Name};
            let query = "MATCH p=(w) -[*]- ()  WHERE w.Name = $nameParam UNWIND relationships(p) AS r WITH r RETURN r, COLLECT(DISTINCT toString(id(endNode(r)))) as s";
            return session.run(query, params)
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.records.map(function (record) {
                        return record.get("s")
                    })
                })
        },
        target: (name, _) => {
            let session = driver.session();
            let params = {nameParam: name.Name};
            let query = "MATCH p=(w) -[*]- () WHERE w.Name = $nameParam UNWIND relationships(p) AS r WITH r RETURN r, COLLECT(DISTINCT toString(id(startNode(r)))) as t";
            return session.run(query, params)
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.records.map(function (record) {
                        return record.get("t")
                    })
                })
        },
    },
};

module.exports = resolveFunctions;
```

This is the schema. I've tried a different query for only the link data and a nested query as the one above. When I try to make a query only for the link data, graphql will return null. I logged the result that gets returned in the resolver and it does display the data as needed. I am not sure why, but graphql still returns null.

It helped to convert the id to strings after changing the Neo4j Query. But .then(...).edges.source.id / edges.source / edges.target all return undefined. at least it's shorter than .edges.source.id.low

In the example below I managed to get the data in the query. But now it returns 4 id's for every single node. Only one target id and one source id should be returned together with a single node, not 4. Might this be solved by providing a different WHERE clause? I tried to solve this issue for another full day. I tried many different Neo4j queries and I tried to change the graphql schema in many ways too. I have a big lack of experience and I'm just a beginner, but I'm dying to figure this out.

```
type Node {
    id: Int
    Name: String
    user: User
    tag: String
    labels: String
    source: String
    target: String
}

type Query {
    nodes(id:Int): [Node]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to take a look at this section on [working with numbers in javascript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type). Neo4j's integer values are 64-bit long values, but javascript can't address these, so you'll need to use the techniques in the linked section to get around this.

Comment: That is not what's causing the problem. You're right, I forgot to add toInteger to the variable in the query here. The problem is that I don't know how to return the value of edges.source.low. It always returns undefined. I tried to find a way to get there as you can see, but I don't know how to use this solution with graphql. I also doubt if it's a good solution in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to convert a long integer into a string using a cypher:

```
{
    edges: COLLECT(DISTINCT {
        source: toString(ID(endNode(r))), 
        target: toString(ID(startNode(r)))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your answer and changed my query according to your advice. Your advice helped a lot, but I didn't manage to solve the problem entirely with it. I've edited the question to show you what it is I can't get to. I hope you have time to have another look at it.